# Tachanun on 7 Adar

Tags: tefilla, tachanun

According to those who don't say tachanun on the seventh of Adar (referenced [here](http://www.thejewishstar.com/stories/Observing-Moses-yartzeit-in-a-leap-year,2267), [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachanun), [here](http://divreichaim.blogspot.com/2008/02/double-adar-and-yahrzeit-of-moshe.html), [here](http://www.ohrtorah.net/downloads/documents/RitualCommittee.pdf) page 3 among others) as it is [traditionally](https://www.ou.org/judaism-101/bh-yom-yom/adar/) considered Moshe Rabbeinu's [yahrzeit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2653/tachanun-on-yahrtzeit), and as such, some don't say it, are there any implications regarding other parts of davening often affected by not saying tachanun? For example, do we say the series of yehi ratzons after the Torah reading which are often connected to tachanun (as [per](http://ph.yhb.org.il/en/03-22-04/) "The Ashkenazim are accustomed to say “Yehi Ratzon” while the Torah is being rolled and covered, except on days that Tachanun is not recited (see Piskei Teshuvot 147:7).) Do we say tachanun on the [mincha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/8005/1362) of the 6th of Adar?

Are there different 'levels' of omission of tachanun depending on the reason (such as overt holiday, explicitly stated simcha, known yahrzeit, traditionally accepted date of yahrzeit) which have different consequences in the rest of davening?

Comment: Do we say the yehi ratzons when there is no tachanun for a different reason? like the presence of a chassan or the ba'alei habris?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I don't know -- my siddur just says (my translation) "On Monday and Thursday when we say tachanun..." but I don't know if that is affected by a local exemption.

Comment: Source requested for "According to those who don't say tachanun on the seventh of Adar" since the Shulchan Aruch has it as a fast day. (Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 580:2) אֵלּוּ הַיָּמִים שֶׁאֵרְעוּ בָּהֶם צָרוֹת לַאֲבוֹתֵינוּ  וְרָאוּי לְהִתְעַנּוֹת בָּהֶם ...  בְּז' בַּאֲדָר מֵת מֹשֶׁה רַבֵּנוּ ע''ה

Comment: @DannySchoemann added. TY.

Comment: Interesting: not a single "halachic source" given by any of the 4 refs. Ref. #1 even says "there is no real precedent in halakha to do this." Maybe I should ask a Q about this.

Comment: @DannySchoemann the aishdas link I found goes to a question asking for a source. None is given as far as I can tell. Is it possible it is just an extension of the minhag not to say tachanun on the day of a tzaddik's yahrzeit and no specific statement of "and Moshe" is necessary?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky- "Yehi ratzon" has a different source and reason. I saw this on "Beureihatefilah.org". Don't recall exact spelling of the link, but you may find it. If not, ping me, later.

Answer (score 1):

Mishnah Berurah [on 147:7 (22)](https://books.google.com/books?id=5tIbPJZCAQ8C&pg=PA263&dq=yehi%20ratzon%20reading%20the%20torah&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Jd7tVIDaFsafNpOUgdgD&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=yehi%20ratzon&f=false) states that the recitation of the Yehi Ratzon is only a minhag and is not mandatory. Regarding reciting it [on Channukah (684:1 (1))](https://books.google.com/books?id=JDK1exYRZNUC&pg=PA227&dq=yehi%20ratzon%20reading%20the%20torah&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Jd7tVIDaFsafNpOUgdgD&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=yehi%20ratzon%20reading%20the%20torah&f=false), he says that we should not recite the Yehi Ratzon after the keriyah on Channukah. He links this to not saying the Kel Erech Apayaim before taking out the Torah.

The [Encyclopedia on Jewish Prayer](https://books.google.com/books?id=pbuPJeQyeskC&pg=PA368&dq=yehi%20ratzon%20reading%20the%20torah%20rosh%20chodesh&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bt_tVOAYg6GDBL6mgcAM&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=yehi%20ratzon%20reading%20the%20torah%20rosh%20chodesh&f=false) states that the Machzor Vitri has us saying the prayer on Shabbos, where no Tachanun is required.

It would appear that there are in fact different "levels" of days in which tachanun, kel erech apayim, and yehi ratzon would be treated differently. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45530/is-%D7%A7%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%9A-%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D-said-if-the-torahs-not-to-be-read-from) for more details.

Yahrtziets don't fall under the same classification as minor holidays vis a vis tachanun. Since 7th Adar isn't an actual holiday, you wouldn't treat the afternoon of the 6th with the additional simcha that leads us to omit tachanun. If it falls on a day of kriyas hatorah (as it does this year), it would appear that you would still say the Yehi Ratzon's after the kriyah, similar to what we do on shabbos and how the chassidim treat every other yahrtziet.

Comment: Again, not a single source in the critical paragraph (the last one) that discusses omitting Tachanun on a Yahrzeit in general and on 7 Adar in particular.

Comment: From https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/zayin-adar/#ftn6 , "The Chabad Rabbeim did not say Tachanun on Zayin Adar starting from the Mincha of Vav Adar. Nevertheless this custom only began once they took leadership of the movement and not beforehand. [Sefer Haminhagim [English] p. 168]"