# Fast days and אל ארך אפים

Tags: sources-mekorot, fast-days, shacharis-morning-prayer, torah-service, mincha-afternoon-prayer

I have heard various opinions about saying [Keil](http://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=add_ms_27200_f041r) [erekh](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=315) [apayim](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43126&pgnum=90) before the Torah reading on fast days.* [Most say](http://din.org.il/2013/06/25/%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%90%D7%A8%D7%9A-%D7%90%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%96-%D7%91%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%96/) that we should only do that if the public fast day falls on Monday or Thursday. What are the main sources discussing this issue and what is their reasoning? What about the reading in the afternoon?

<sup>* Not the one said in the *viduy* according to *nusach sefard.*</sup>

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Don't people usually say fast-day selichot between chazarat haShatz and the Torah reading, regardless of what day of the week it is?

Comment: @Harel13 If you ask me, I am supposed to say it _in_ the repetition. But in the afternoon prayer you don't have _selichot._ [Another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/45530/15256) is whether _Keil erekh apayim_ belongs to the _tachanun_ or the Torah reading service.

Comment: The question is about א-ל ארך אפים ורב חסד ואמת, not א-ל ארך אפים אתה ובעל הרחמים נקראת